# Ways of retaining data from web form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, caching

I have a function to code where I need to enter details of an student in a web form.
The system will do 2 verifications:
 If the email address of the student is in the system.
 If the name of the student is in the system.
 If any of the above is true then the system will send the list of matches in a new page for user of system to check if the student is already in the system or not.  If not, the new student is created in system by clicking on the create new button in the web page.

My question is how do I store the information obtained in the 1st web form so as to be able to create a new student in case it does not exit.  Do I need to create a new model to collect the details from the 1st web form or is there any other way of doing this?  Cause I will not be needing the web form data if the student already exist.
I am coding in .net 4.6 and MVC5.

Comment: Why not just use ajax to call a server method that does the validation so that you stay in the same page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: because the check will have to be done manually by user of system.  This is the requirement.

Comment: I guess you did not understand my comment. You can use ajax to post the data to a method that returns a partial view of the 'list of matches' and show it on the current page. But if you do want to make a redirect, then you need to persist your data somewhere (e.g. in `Session`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : So you mean I use ajax to do the verification and display.  then in case of a new student, I can use the ajax ''object'' to save it?  Do you have any example pls?

Comment: What I mean is that you use ajax to send the value of the student name and email address to a method to do your verification, and return a partial view of the 'list of matches'. The use can then just submit the form after they have 'manually checked' it

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  So I will first have a web form to enter student details.  Then on submit, it will do the necessary verifications and then display the results in a partial view which will have a table and a create button.  The previous webform will not be shown.  So when the user click on create new student where will the controller get the details previously entered in the webform?  I assume there will be a view model for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168273/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tabby).